# Getting column INT value from a specific user

Tags: php, mysql, database

First time posting here, so I hope I did everything right!

I am trying to receive the subscription days of my users saved in a column, and save it into a variable in php to print it out with echo to use it on my loader later on (I know what to do in the loader).

So my question is, how can I receive the remaining sub days from a specific user in my users table?

that's what I've tried:

```
$sub_query = "SELECT subscription_ FROM users WHERE username ='".$loader_username."'";
```

`$loader_username` is a variable where `$_GET['username']` is saved in.

Best regards!

Comment: What is the structure of the table ? Note that your query is vulnerable to SQL injections, use prepared statements

Comment: thanks for your answer, what exactly do you mean by structure? I should have mentioned that it's my second day with PHP and that I didn't have much experience with databases yet ^^

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection if you execute this query. You should use prepared statements.

Comment: By structure, I mean the description (name and type) of each fields (AKA column)

Comment: I save the sub time in the INT column subscription_ in the table wp_users

Comment: @Invictus, 1. What do you mean by "remaining sub days"? Is this different than what is in column subscription_? And is the table named wp_users or users. Try to be precise when you ask a question.

Comment: table is called users and subscription_ is the column where the sub days are saved as INT.